# XYChart data: Compiling transaction amount per Object type

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to wrap my head around how to do the following: Iterate through a list of transactions and compile the amount of total transactions per card type, so that the data can be visually represented with a StackedBarChart.

I have two classes with the constructors and getters/setters, one representing the Transaction object, the other class represents the CreditCard.

```
  public class Transaction {

    private String type;
    private double amount;
    private CreditCard creditCard;

    public Transaction(String type, double amount, CreditCard creditCard) {
        this.type = type;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.creditCard = creditCard;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public CreditCard getCreditCard() {
        return creditCard;
    }

    public void setCreditCard(CreditCard creditCard) {
        this.creditCard = creditCard;
    }
    }
```

And the Credit Card Class:

```
public class CreditCard {

private String company;
private String cardName;

public CreditCard(String company, String cardName) {
    this.company = company;
    this.cardName = cardName;
}

public String getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(String company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public String getCardName() {
    return cardName;
}

public void setCardName(String cardName) {
    this.cardName = cardName;
}
}
```

I have an ObservableList which contains all the transactions made, and create another one to contain this years transactions.

```
private ObservableList<Trade> tradeList;
 private List<Transaction> thisYearsTransactions;
```

For simplicity, I am omitting the complete Controller code, but using a third class I get a list of all the current years transactions.

I think having the number of card companies would help compile transactions for each, but I am stuck.

```
thisYearsTransactions = dataCalculations.getThisYearsTransactions(transactions)

List<CreditCard) cardList = new ArrayList<CreditCard>();

for(Transaction transaction : thisYearsTransaction) {
CreditCard card = transaction.getCreditCard();
String cardComp = card.getComp();
 if(!cardList.contains(cardComp){
     cardList.add(cardComp);
}
}
```

What would be the best approach to iterate through the list, and compile the total amount per card?
Since we don't know how many card types there are, I am assuming I need to compile a List of cardtypes, then use that list when iterating through the transactions and compile for each card?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to group all the transactions according to the credit card company and for each group you want to sum the `amount` from each `Transaction` instance. Is that correct?

Comment: what's the relation to javafx?

Comment: That is right @Abra

Comment: @kleopatra because I want to display the data in a StackedBarChart, that part I understand, grouping the data however is where I am struggling

Comment: I think that's the point @kleopatra is trying to make. If you understand the JavaFX part then JavaFX is irrelevant to your question; including it only clouds the issue.

Comment: You basically want a `Map<String, Double>`, yes? So create one, loop over the transactions list, use the credit card company name as the key for the map, and then sum the current transaction's amount with the value already mapped to that key. If there is no mapping yet then just put the amount in directly. See `Map#merge(...)`. You could also use streams and collect with `Collectors#groupingBy(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) that was introduced in Java 8 to create a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) where the `Map` key is the credit card company name and the `Map` value is the total amount of all the transactions made by credit cards belonging to that company.

```java
/* Required imports:
 * import java.util.List;
 * import java.util.Map;
 * import java.util.function.Function;
 * import java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction;
 * import java.util.stream.Collector;
 * import java.util.stream.Collectors;
 */
List<Transaction> thisYearsTransactions = dataCalculations.getThisYearsTransactions(transactions);
Function<Transaction, String> classifier = t -> t.getCreditCard().getCompany();
ToDoubleFunction<Transaction> mapper = t -> t.getAmount();
Collector<Transaction, ?, Double> downstream = Collectors.summingDouble(mapper);
Map<String, Double> map = thisYearsTransactions.stream()
                                               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(classifier,
                                                                              downstream));
```

- `classifier`, in the above code, is a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) that provides the `Map` key.
- `downstream` sums all the `amount`s using `mapper`.
- `mapper` is another lambda expression that simply returns the `amount` from each `Transaction`.

References:

- [Aggregate Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html) lesson in Oracle's Java tutorials.
- [Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html) article from *Java Magazine*, March/April 2014 issue.

Comment: This works, thanks for your help. I might add that this will throw an exception when trying to map a NULL value.